# xcode 8 provisioning profile error

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, provisioning

I have an app that I created with xcode 7.3.  I have updated to xcode 8 and I am trying to update my app.  I see the provisioning profile I used before under provisioning profile (depreciated) but there is nothing under provisioning profile.  Do I need to create a new iOS Distribution certificate for my developer account? I am getting the "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found." error.  I know there is already some answers found on this site but I am fairly new to xcode and I don't completely understand them.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create new distribution profile as Xcode have option **Automatically manage signing** you only need to select the **Team** and if have already registered the bundle identifier xcode will create everything for now its very easy.

Please let me know if you have any further error.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize all I had to do was make sure the check box was clicked.  All Good!  I appreciate your answer it was helpful.

Comment: Where is this option "Automatically manage signing"? I want to disable it and select my provisioning profile.

Comment: you can find this option only in Xcode 8 other wise you can use lower version of Xcode.